# What word to use meaning as much as "veggie-ism"?

Tags: word-request

When saying "Peter is vegetarian" and "Jonas is non-vegetarian" and "Niclas is vegan", how could i express that in one word, such as:

"What is your *veggie-ism*?", "My *veggie-ism* is vegan!".

That is just an example which sounds stupid. I am looking for a word that applies in that context. A word that i can use instead of "veggie-ism". Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We definitely don't have a word for this. If you wanted to ask a question, the usual question is "Do you have any dietary restrictions?" Otherwise, we just fumble around with multiple words.